# layout 3 columns and 2 columns height does not match

Tags: html, css

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vyBYc.png)

Image size is 100% width.

Trying to make two columns and three columns below.

Fourth and fifth column height does not match the column height.

padding-right 5px must also apply.

a,b,c = image size (224x224)

d = image size (448x224)

e = image size (224x224)

How can I do this?

```
<div id="box-wrapper">
<div class="box-banner">
<div class="box-button"><a href="#"><img src="/224/random/ffffff"></a></div>
<div class="box-button"><a href="#"><img src="/224/random/ffffff"></a></div>
<div class="box-button"><a href="#"><img src="/224/random/ffffff"></a></div>
</div>
<div class="box-banner-two">
<div class="box-button-two"><a href="#"><img src="/448x224/random/ffffff"></a></div>
<div class="box-button-two"><a href="#"><img src="/224/random/ffffff"></a></div>
</div>
</div>

#box-wrapper {
padding-top: 10px !important;
padding-left: 5px !important;
padding-right: 5px !important;
height: 100%;
position: relative;
float: left;
}

.box-banner,
.box-banner-two {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: relative;
float: left;
}
.box-button {
float: left;
width: 32.444%;
margin: 0 5px 5px 0;
}
.box-button img,
.box-button-two img {
width: 100%;
}

.box-banner .box-button:nth-child(3) {
margin-right: 0px;
float: right !important;
}
.box-banner-two .box-button-two:nth-child(1) {
float: left;
width: 64.888%;
margin: 0 5px 5px 0;
}
.box-banner-two .box-button-two:nth-child(2) {
float: right;
width:32.444%;
margin: 0 5px 5px 0;
margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean match the height or the width? Because they match the height... not the width

Comment: @Sandrina Pereira Please refer to the screenshot.
Thank you.

Comment: I understood but there is nothing you can't do. If you want a padding between images and the image size is fixed, it's mathematical, right? The only solution here would be increase the image size... let me do a codepen for you

Comment: @SandrinaPereira Thank you.
I wonder what the reason should not.
In Mobile wants to use the image width to 100%.

Comment: check my answer below :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your are over complicating stuff with margin and paddings. The secret here is using `box-sizing: border-box.` [Understand it better here](https://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/)

Apply the `box-sizing` to the .banner and its childrens

```
.banner {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.banner * {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
```

Also apply to the `img` the `width` and `padding` you need

```
.banner img {
  width: 100%;
}
.banner > * {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

To better help you on layout add `col-` classes to each img parent

```
.col1-3 {
  width: 33.333%;
}

.col2-3 {
  width: 66.666%;
}
```

The html:

```
<div class="banner cf">
    <div class="col1-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://www.okcourtsidehoops.com/okcourtsidehoops/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/images-21.jpg" /></a></div>
    <div class="col1-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://www.okcourtsidehoops.com/okcourtsidehoops/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/images-21.jpg" /></a></div>
    <div class="col1-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://www.okcourtsidehoops.com/okcourtsidehoops/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/images-21.jpg" /></a></div>

</div>

<div class="banner cf">
    <div class="col2-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://www.amnh.org/var/ezflow_site/storage/images/media/amnh/images/learn-teach/program-images/teacher-programs-images-folder/data-viz-images-folder/data-viz-webinar-image-3/655567-3-eng-US/data-viz-webinar-image-3_imagelarge.jpg" /></a></div>
    <div class="col1-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://www.okcourtsidehoops.com/okcourtsidehoops/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/images-21.jpg" /></a></div>  
</div>
```

A working example:
http://codepen.io/sandrina-p/pen/PGQKrQ

Comment: Thank you.
col2-3 height of the net is not going to meet the same rules as col1-3 height?

Comment: check it again, you have to choose. or match the width or match the height. otherwise you need to cut the image with "overflow: hidden" on .banner > *

Comment: Thank you.
It has been a great help.

Comment: I'll ask you one thing more.

If you cut the size of the image col2-3 Is somehow?

Comment: I cut the size of col2-3 with overflow: hidden.  Did it help you?

Comment: Yes.
Without cropping the image using jquery it has to apply the height value of the col 1-3. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I modified the html and css posted by you to achieve the same effect. I hope this helps.

Try to avoid important as much as possible.

```css
*, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: burlywood;
  height: 224px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 224px;
}
#box-wrapper {
  padding: 10px 5px 0 5px;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.clearfix:after {
  display: table;
  clear: both;
  content: '';
}
.box-button {
  float: left;
  width: 33.333%;
  padding: 0 5px 5px 0;
}
.col-2 {
  width: 66.666%;
}
```

```html
<div id="box-wrapper">
  <div class="box-banner clearfix">
    <div class="box-button">
      <a href="#">A Link</a>
    </div>
    <div class="box-button">
      <a href="#">A Link</a>
    </div>
    <div class="box-button">
      <a href="#">A Link</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box-banner clearfix">
    <div class="box-button col-2">
      <a href="#">A Link</a>
    </div>
    <div class="box-button">
      <a href="#">A Link</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great job! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```css
#box-wrapper {
padding-top: 10px !important;
padding-left: 5px !important;
padding-right: 5px !important;
height: 100%;
position: relative;

}

.box-banner,
.box-banner-two {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: relative;
float: left;
}
.box-button {
float: left;
width: 32.444%;
margin: 0 5px 5px 0;
}
.box-button img,
.box-button-two img {
width: 100%;
}

.box-banner .box-button:nth-child(3) {

float: right !important;
}
.box-banner-two .box-button-two:nth-child(1) {
float: left;
width: 64.888%;
margin: 0 5px 5px 0;
}
.box-banner-two .box-button-two:nth-child(2) {
float: right;
width:32.444%;
margin: 0 5px 5px 0;
margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="box-wrapper">
<div class="box-banner">
<div class="box-button"><a href="#"><img src="/224/random/ffffff"></a></div>
<div class="box-button"><a href="#"><img src="/224/random/ffffff"></a></div>
<div class="box-button"><a href="#"><img src="/224/random/ffffff"></a></div>
</div>
<div class="box-banner-two">
<div class="box-button-two"><a href="#"><img src="/448x224/random/ffffff"></a></div>
<div class="box-button-two"><a href="#"><img src="/224/random/ffffff"></a></div>
</div>
  <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

Comment: Sorry.
I was wrong question.
Please see the screenshots again.